# State of a particle - free vs interacting

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, quantum-spin

It is often said and used that we can describe the state of a free spinless particle by just it's momentum.

Is the motivation for such statements coming from Hamiltonian formulation of dynamics? In which we describe a system using its Hamiltonian and if the system is free then, of course, momentum is sufficient to describe everything about it. And if the system is interacting then we would need it's momentum and it's energy (or the potential).

I have an intuition that somehow we can describe the state of an interacting particle by it's momentum alone, though we would need to consider an "effective" momentum sort of description (what would its fourier transform correspond to?). Can someone please help me with thoughts on this? If this intuition is correct then is it universal or is it true only for a specific class of theories?

Also, if we compare the case of going from free particle to interacting particle vs spinless particle to particle with spin there is a curious observation (please correct me if I am wrong) : when considering interacting particles we add terms directly to the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian but when we consider particles with spin (say, Dirac equation) the Lagrangian contains terms (Dirac spinors) which depend on the spin but there is no direct spin operator (etc.) appearing in the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian. Why is that?

Comment: It is not very clear what is the question in the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to consider quantum mechanics.

A system in quantum mechanics is described by its state, namely a vector in the Hilbert space. You can choose a basis of this Hilbert space, such that each vector of the basis is eigenstate of a complete set of
observables. In this sense, you can describe the state of the system by a complete set of quantum numbers, e.g. momentum, spin, etc.
This is valid **independently** on whether the system is interacting or not.

In the case of a spinless particle, you need only momentum *or position* to describe the state of the particle. Again, this is *independent* on whether the particle is free or not. The difference between free and interacting particle is that in the former case the state with definite momentum is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. One usually says that in this case momentum *is a good quantum number.*

To answer your question: if we take them literally, your statements are wrong.
The state of a spinless particle can *in any case* be described by momentum only.